# webapi batching and delegating handlers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, batch-processing

based on my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998556/webapi-batch-requests/11998600#11998600) I was able to get batching working... until a certain point. In addition to registering the route specific handler I also have 2 delegating handlers

1. Authenticate the user
2. logging

the batch handler goes through the delegating handlers authenticating the user and logging the request. when the messagehandlerinvoker starts to send the child/nested requests the following exception is thrown.

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'AuthenticationMessageHandler' is not null.
Parameter name: handlers
  Source=System.Net.Http.Formatting
  ParamName=handlers
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, IEnumerable`1 handlers)
       at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.Initialize()
       at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<EnsureInitialized>b__3()
       at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
       at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
       at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.EnsureInitialized()
       at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at RoutingRequest.Service.Startup.BatchMessageHandler.<>c__DisplayClassd.<PrcoessRequest>b__b(Task`1 m) in C:\CEI\Clients\Footlocker.com\FL - Vendor Routing Portal\source\RoutingRequest.Service\Startup\BatchMessageHandler.cs:line 45
       at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
  InnerException:
```

is there a config option I am missing, or do I need to bypass the delegating handlers?

**edit**
here is my authentication handler.

```
public class AuthenticationMessageHandler
    : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        SetCurrentUser(request);
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void SetCurrentUser(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var values = new List<string>().AsEnumerable();
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("routingrequest-username", out values) == false) return;

        var username = values.First();

        var user = Membership.GetUser(username, true);
        if (user == null)
        {
            var message = string.Format("membership information for '{0}' could not be found.", username);
            throw new HttpRequestException(message);
        }

        var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user.UserName), roles);
    }
}
```

based on Kiran's answer a subclassed httpserver fixes one issue and introduces another. My roles provider is getting a null reference exception. looking into that now.

Comment: could you post your authentication handler code and its initialization code?

Answer (score 19):

That blog post correctly identifies the problem, but there is a simpler solution if you are configuring OWIN using a `Startup` or `OwinStartup` class:

Change the OWIN configuration call from
`UseWebApi(this IAppBuilder builder, HttpConfiguration configuration);`
to
`UseWebApi(this IAppBuilder builder, HttpServer httpServer);`
so that your batch handler and the OWIN pipeline are using the same `HttpServer` instance.

The root cause of this is that many of the batching articles/examples (eg http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/batching-handler-for-web-api.html ) create a new `HttpServer` for batching in addition to the main `HttpServer` that is handling HTTP requests; and both `HttpServer`s are using the same `HttpConfiguration`.

When each `HttpServer` is initialized the first time it receives requests, it creates a pipeline of handlers (in `HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline`) by reversing all the configured delegating handlers (eg tracing handlers, or other proxy-type handlers), and terminating the pipeline with the Web API dispatcher.

If you don't have any delegating handlers configured, then this problem won't bite you - you can have 2 `HttpServer` objects that use the same `HttpConfiguration`.

But if you have any delegating handlers explicitly or implicitly configured (eg by [enabling Web API Tracing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api)), then Web API can't build the 2nd pipeline - the delegating handlers are already linked in the first pipeline - and this exception is thrown on the first request to the 2nd `HttpServer`.

This exception should absolutely be more clear about what is going on.  Better yet, this problem shouldn't even be possible - configuration should be configuration, not individual handlers.  The configuration could be a factory for delegating handlers.  But I digress...

While the issue is kinda hard to figure out, there's a pretty easy fix:

1. If you're using OWIN, pass the same `HttpServer` as you use in the batch handler to the OWIN pipeline via `UseWebApi(this IAppBuilder builder, HttpServer httpServer);`
2. If you're using IIS + Web API (no OWIN Startup class), pass `GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer` to your batch handler, to avoid creating a new `HttpServer`

Here's an example OWIN startup class that creates a single `HttpServer` and passes it to both the batch handler, and Web API.  This example uses to OData batch handler:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(My.Web.OwinStartup))]
namespace My.Web
{

    /// <summary>
    /// OWIN webapp configuration.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class OwinStartup
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure all the OWIN modules that participate in each request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">The OWIN appBuilder</param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration webApiConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
            webApiConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            HttpServer webApiServer = new HttpServer(webApiConfig);

            // Configure batch handler
            var batchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(webApiServer);
            webApiConfig.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute",
                                                     "odata",
                                                     BuildEdmModel(),
                                                     new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
                                                     ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault(),
                                                     batchHandler);

            app.UseWebApi(webApiServer);
        }

        private EdmModel BuildEdmModel()
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: interesting! In the default ` public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` of startup.cs (where OWIN by default configures Cors & co), how would I get the httpServer? Thanks

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Comment: Call `IOC` initialization after `UseWebApi` otherwise you may get error "Cannot reuse an 'ApiController' instance. 'ApiController' has to be constructed per incoming message. Check your custom 'IHttpControllerActivator' and make sure that it will not manufacture the same instance.". In my case they were `UseAutofacMiddleware` and `UseAutofacWebApi`

Comment: @crimbo I'm using `OWIN` just for `SignalR`, and there is no `UseWebApi` method. What's the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error without batching. I made an `HttpClientFactory` of my own and it takes in a `HandlerFactory`, also my own.

It calls the `HandlerFactory.Create()` method in the constructor and stores the resulting handlers that it made.

These are passed to the `System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory.Create(...)` method whenever the factory needs to make a new `HttpClient`.

But it's then only good for a single call because the handlers themselves are mutated by the .NET code leaving them in a state that means they cannot be reused.

I altered my constructor so that it doesn't create the handlers up front, but each time. It now works.