# Web API 'in memory' requests throw exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Ok, my situation is much more complicated but there is an easy way to reproduce. Starting with a fresh new **ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application** project and selecting Web API as a template I just add a second mvc action to the HomeController where I need to call Web API internally.

```
 public async Task<string> TestAPI()
    {
        HttpServer server = new HttpServer(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        using (HttpMessageInvoker messageInvoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(server, false))
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:58233/api/values");
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = messageInvoker.SendAsync(request, new CancellationToken()).Result;
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        //server.Dispose(); - if I do that on the second request I get a "Cannot access a disposed object." exception
    }
```

that thing works only on the first request. On subsequent requests it throws with

> The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property
>   'InnerHandler' of 'RequestMessageHandlerTracer' is not null. Parameter
>   name: handlers

I really need to use the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration here since my system is very modular/plugin based, which makes it really hard to reconstruct that configuration within the action method(or anywhere else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying to re-use the HttpServer instance on secondary requests.  Creating and configuring a new server on every request is not an expected usage and you are likely hitting some edge case.  Either setup a DI mechanism and inject into your controller a singleton of the HttpServer, or try accessing it from some static property.

I also would suggest using `new HttpClient(httpServer)` instead of HttpMessageInvoker.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue can occur in Web API, if you have multiple `HttpServer`s using the same configuration object, and the configuration contains a non-empty list of delegating handlers.

The error occurs because MVC/Web API builds a pipeline of handlers on first request, containing all the delegating handlers (eg `RequestMessageHandlerTracer` if request tracing is enabled) linked to each other, followed by the MVC server handler.

If you have multiple `HttpServer`s using the same configuration object, and the config object contains delegating handlers, the first `HttpServer` will be successfully connected into a pipeline; but the second one won't, because the delegating handlers are already connected - instead it will throw this exception on first request/initialization.

More detail on the Web API case here (which is conceptually identical, but uses different classes and would have a slightly different fix):
[webapi batching and delegating handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008686/webapi-batching-and-delegating-handlers/31445355#31445355)

In my opinion, the MVC configuration classes should be pure config, and not contain actual delegating handlers.  Instead, the configuration classes should create new delegating handlers upon initialization.  Then this bug wouldn't exist.